# How do I force Recoll to not check file contents?

Tags: recoll

I'm trying to simulate the usefulness of the Everything search tool on Windows. Recoll is the only application that comes near it. However, the database it makes is massive (around 2 GB). I think it's because it's also indexing the file contents, instead of just the file names. How do I stop this?

Comment: Although you might be able to [search based on file names](http://askubuntu.com/a/243898/402004) Recoll is designed to search file contents, not file names. Searching by file names is trivial and is built into any OS.

Comment: @Ron Yes, but Recoll is the only one I've found that is instantaneous

Comment: locate only works if have updated db. whenever I move files/folders, the db is out-dated. I then run updatedb and it takes forever to update (because I want to find/locate on my media storage too).

Voidtools Everything on Windows was super fast since it only does filename.
locate/find requires a bit of learning curve just to be able to find a folder with just the middle part of the name.
Currently trying Recoll since I too find it looks very similar to Everything on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can add the following line to $HOME/.recoll/recoll.conf:

```
indexedmimetypes = none
```

But, as Ron noted, this does not make much sense. 'locate' or any as its front-ends will do the job, just as "instantaneously"

Comment: I had to install locate, find comes with Ubuntu default. 22.04

oh how I wish recoll had examples in it's manual

https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.pdf